# Interpretation of Interaction coefficients in GLM using categorical predictors (in R)

Tags: categorical-data, generalized-linear-model, interaction

I ran a Gamma GLM using 3 categorical predictors:

1. Year - with 4 classes
2. Organ - with 3 classes
3. Site - with 3 classes

My response variable is Biomass.

My model is:

```
GLM <- glm(biom ~ fyear + organ + site + year:organ + year:site + organ:site,
       data = data, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
```

The summary(GLM) gives me this (3 coefficients are not defined because of singularities):

```
                  Estimate   Std.Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)        3.34408    0.39101   8.552 7.89e-14 ***
year2             -0.55195    0.29480  -1.872  0.06382 .  
year3              0.65445    0.29480   2.220  0.02847 *  
year4             -0.20425    0.29616  -0.690  0.49186    
organ2             1.62266    0.39846   4.072 8.80e-05 ***
organ3             2.64728    0.33840   7.823 3.40e-12 ***
site2              1.01485    0.53400   1.900  0.05999 . 
site3              0.41056    0.52632   0.780  0.43703    
year2:organ2       0.03728    0.29480   0.126  0.89959    
year3:organ2      -0.03519    0.29480  -0.119  0.90520    
year4:organ2      -2.03455    0.30021  -6.777 6.34e-10 ***
year2:organ3          NA         NA      NA       NA    
year3:organ3          NA         NA      NA       NA    
year4:organ3          NA         NA      NA       NA    
year2:site2        0.78444    0.36105   2.173  0.03195 *  
year3:site2       -0.01524    0.36105  -0.042  0.96641    
year4:site2        0.28738    0.37216   0.772  0.44166    
year2:site3        1.04849    0.36105   2.904  0.00445 ** 
year3:site3        0.08768    0.36105   0.243  0.80858    
year4:site3        0.71053    0.36105   1.968  0.05159 .  
organ2:site2      -1.41692    0.48655  -2.912  0.00435 ** 
organ3:site2      -1.59445    0.48655  -3.277  0.00140 ** 
organ2:site3      -0.86975    0.47763  -1.821  0.07133 .  
organ3:site3      -1.30913    0.47763  -2.741  0.00715 **
```

1. **The first coefficient** (3.34408) is the intercept, so it stands for biomass for the year 1, site 1 and organ 1.
2. **The second** one (-0.55195) is the difference between the mean biomass of the year 2 and year 1.
3. **The third** one (0.65445) is the difference between the mean biomass of the year 3 and year 1.
4. **the 4th** (-0.20425) is the difference between the mean biomass of the year 4 and year 1.
5. **The 5th** (1.62266) is the difference between the mean biomass on organ 2 and organ 1.

**...and so on until the 8th coefficient**
After the main coefficients start the interactions.

1. What is their interpretation? YEAR2*ORGAN2 is the difference between what?
2. In addition, year 3 significantly differs from year 1 while year 4 doesn't. What happens between year 3 and year 4? Do they significantly differ?

Comment: I also used glht function from the multcomp package but i get this error: Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) : 
  dimensions of coefficients and covariance matrix don't match

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation should be slightly different:

- **The second** one (-0.55195) is the difference between the mean biomass of the year 2 and year 1 **For observations with intercept values on other categories, namely organ1 and year1**.
- **The third** one (0.65445) is the difference between the mean biomass of the year 3 and year 1 **For observations with intercept values on other categories, namely organ1 and year1**
- etc.

The interaction effect is the difference in main effect with other categories on other variables. So **the eight** one (YEAR2*ORGAN2) is the difference between observations with year1 and organ1 versus year2 and organ2 (in addition to the main effect).

About your second question: you can't really answer that based on this table, since all first categories are the reference group. I think you should run a pairwise comparison of groups to answer that question.

Comment: What pairwise comparison is the best after a GLM? Is bonferroni suitable?

Comment: So for example in the second one it's the comparison between (year2, organ1, site1) and (year2, organ1, site1). The third is (year1, organ1, site1) and (year3, organ1, site1)...and so on! But how can we know about the global main effect of year or site or organ?

Comment: Bonferroni is suitable but might be a bit conservative (it corrects for multiple testing quit harsh). Your second comment: there is no global main effect of a categorical variable. The effect is different for every category.

Comment: Thank you @Ivo. So the interpretation you describe is always like a tree-way interaction...eg for YEAR3 is year3,organ1,site1 vs year1,organ1,site1? But for the interactions eg for YEAR2:SITE2 is year2,site2 vs year1,site1 or year2,site2,organ1 vs year1,site1,organ1?

Comment: YEAR3: yes. YEAR2:SITE2 is the additional effect (on top of main effects) if YEAR2:SITE2 occur together and organ1 is at basecase. So its both year2, site2, organ1 vs year2, site1, organ1 and year2, site2, organ1 vs year1, site2, organ1. Interpretation gets quite tricky with several categorical variables. By the way: you might want to consider using a random effect model whereby you include year and site as a random effect.

Comment: Yes it's very tricky...On a paper someone would like to report results related to differences between eg Sites. This output gives more detailed information than this eg Site 1,Year1, Organ1 vs Site2, Year1, Organ1. Maybe I will stick with likelihood ratio test results...Random effects are not good for my interpretation because i want to discuss for specific years and organs. Thank you again @Ivo!